# How to obtain multiple tuples using pythons findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to obtain multiple tuples from the following 'text' using python findall()

```
text = '[szur formatter] line 1<?xml version="1.0"?><star>[szur parser] line 2<?xml version="1.0"?><Planet>'
```

I want to get the following matching patterns from 'text'

```
    Match 1
    [szur formatter] line 1 
    <?xml version="1.0"?><star>

    Match 2
    [szur parser] line 2
    <?xml version="1.0"?><Planet>
```

I'm trying to do this with findall using this regex

```
re.findall(r'\[(szur.*?[^<])(<.*>+)', text)
```

this yields

```
[('szur formatter] line 1', '<?xml version="1.0"?><star>[szur parser] line 2<?xml version="1.0"?><Planet>')]
```

How to get the expected results. My regex doesn't yield the second tuple. How do I need to amend my regex to obtain this? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: `(\[szur.*?[^\[<]+)([^\[]+)` ? https://regex101.com/r/EaPBwA/2

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regexp that makes some assumptions:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(\[szur.*?[^\]]\] line \d*)([^\[]*)", text)
[('[szur formatter] line 1', '<?xml version="1.0"?><star>'), 
 ('[szur parser] line 2',    '<?xml version="1.0"?><Planet>')]
```

But seriously, man, if you find yourself parsing a mix of XML and non-XML with regexp, ask yourself: "how did I get here?"

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a good idea (using regular expressions, that is) but here you go:

```
\[szur[^][]*\].*?<\w+>
```

Use the `DOTALL` modifier and see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8KzrSs/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

string = """[szur formatter] line 1<?xml version="1.0"?><star>[szur parser] line 2<?xml version="1.0"?><Planet>"""

rx = re.compile(r'(\[szur[^][]*\].*?<\w+>)')

matches = rx.findall(string)
# matches = rx.findall(string, re.DOTALL)
print(matches)
```